# Getting AttributeError: 'TestCase' object has no attribute 'assertTemplateUsed' when trying to unit test views.py using unittest framework

Tags: django, unit-testing, python-unittest

Here is my code for unit test fruit view. But getting **AttributeError**

**test_views.py**

```
class TestViews(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_fruit_GET(self):
        client = Client()
        response = client.get(reverse('products:fruit'))
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'products/fruit.html')
```

**views.py**

```
def fruit(request):

    product = Product.objects.filter(category="Fruit")
    n = Product.objects.filter(category="Fruit").count()
    params = {'product': product, 'n': n}
    return render(request, 'products/fruit.html', params)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is part of django's TestCase class, so you need to use it instead:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class TestViews(TestCase):

    def test_fruit_GET(self):
        client = Client()
        response = client.get(reverse('products:fruit'))
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'products/fruit.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not available for the `unittest.TestCase`. This is provided by Django's [**`TestCase`** class [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase), so:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class TestViews(TestCase):

    def test_fruit_GET(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('products:fruit'))
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'products/fruit.html')
```

You can implement this yourself, but it is very inconvenient:

```
def assertTemplateUsed(self, response, template_name):
    self.assertIn(
        template_name,
        [t.name for t in response.templates if t.name is not None]
    )
```

Comment: Hi @Willem Van Onsem I need another help regarding this unittest. Could you spare a moment?